# Select Multiple table on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I get the problem when I try to select table using DB on Laravel, in my controller nothing error, but when I try using `dd()`, the data still empty

**SQL**

```
SELECT monthname(od.created_at) AS bulan,  c.name AS name, round(SUM(od.price * od.qty * (100 - od.discount)/ 100),2) AS total
FROM order_details od, categories c, products p 
WHERE p.id = od.product_id 
AND p.category_id = c.id 
GROUP BY c.id, MONTH(od.created_at);
```

result on mysql
[image]

**Controller**

```
$categories = DB::table(DB::raw('categories, order_details, products '))
                        ->select(DB::raw('monthname(order_details.created_at) AS bulan,  categories.name AS name, round(SUM(order_details.price * order_details.qty * (100 - order_details.discount)/ 100),2) AS total'))
                        ->fromRaw('categories, order_details, products ')
                        ->where('products.id', '=', 'order_details.product_id')
                        ->where('products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                        ->groupByRaw('bulan, name')->get();

dd($categories);
```

and this is the result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you wanna do like this ?  we could use join.

```
DB::table('categories')->join('products','products.category_id','categories.id')
                 ->join('order_details','order_details.product_id','products.id)
                 ->select('........
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).